# Prove that an associative operation* is a structural property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First off how does one prove that an operation $\ast$ is a structural property and how is this different from just proving an isomorphism?

My main question is: how can I prove that $\ast$ on a binary structure is a structural property.

So far I have said:
Let $\langle S,\ast\rangle$ and $\langle T,\sharp\rangle$ be two arbitrary binary structures preserved by an isomorphism $f: S\to T$.

Assume $\ast$ is associative

Then we have that $f((a\ast b)\ast c)=f(a\ast b)\sharp c$ for all $a,b$ in $S$
Due to associativity we have that $f(a\ast (b\ast c))=f(a)\sharp f(b\ast c) \ldots$.
And I don't know if I can reach any end from here.

How should I continue? Or restart?

Comment: What is your definition of "structural property"?

Comment: Structural property of a binary structure is one shared by any isomorphic structure

Comment: "Structural property" is certainly not a standard term. So could you explain this further. An isomorphism is usually thought of as a bijection which preserves structure (such as binary operations, inverses etc). So it is hard to think of a property defined in terms of the structure which is not a "structural property". Unless, maybe, there is some confusion about what structure the isomorphism relates to.

Comment: Examples of a structural property may be: set has 4 elements, operation is commutative, or x*x=x for all x in S. What is not a structural property may be: the number10 is an element, the operation is called addition or the elements of S are matrices.

Comment: @matsmv You are trying to prove that _associativity_ is a structural property.  $*$ is not a property, it is an operation, so saying that it is a structural property makes no sene.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description of "structural property", you seem to have started out correctly.  What you need to show is that, if $\langle S,\ast\rangle$ and $\langle T,\sharp\rangle$ are two binary structures and $f:S\to T$ is an isomorphism between them, then $\langle S,\ast\rangle$ is associative if, and only if, $\langle T,\sharp\rangle$ is associative.  By symmetry, it suffices to assume that $\langle S,\ast\rangle$ is associative, and show that $\langle T,\sharp\rangle$ is associative.

Suppose then that $x,y,z\in T$; we need to show that $(x\sharp y)\sharp z = x\sharp(y\sharp z)$.  Since $f$ is an isomorphism, it has an inverse map $f^{-1}$ that is also an isomorphism. Therefore, there exist $a,b,c\in S$ for which $x = f(a)$, $y = f(b)$ and $z = f(c)$. Then
$$(x\sharp y)\sharp z = (f(a)\sharp f(b))\sharp f(c) = f(a\ast b)\sharp f(c) = f((a\ast b)\ast c),$$
since $f$ is a homomorphism. But, since $\ast$ is associative, the argument $(a\ast b)\ast c$ of $f$ is equal to $a\ast(b\ast c)$, so you can unravel the right hand side to eventually get $x\sharp (y\sharp z)$.  (I'll leave this for you.)  That proves that $\langle T,\sharp\rangle$ is associative as well.